# Pass custom parameters with the authorization request using lua-resty-openidc

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty, resty, lua-resty-openidc

I'm using [lua-resty-openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc) to configure NGINX as an OIDC RP with my Authorization Server.

My requirement is to pass a value from the initial request coming to the Nginx (from the browser, let's say a query param), in the authorization code request to the Authorization Server (from Nginx).

Is there a way to achieve this? Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass custom parameters by setting `opts.authorization_params` as shown in the sample in `README.md` and here:
https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc/blob/master/lib/resty/openidc.lua#L309